# stop code formatting through modifying AST in Eclipse CDT

Tags: formatting, eclipse-cdt, abstract-syntax-tree

I am editing a cod pragmatically through editing the AST in Eclipse CDT, put after perform the refactor using Change#perform method, I found the code to be formatted, example here I am just cast a function call to be void

```
//Old code
Publish(Author_id, Content);

//New code
(void) Publish(
                Author_id,
                Content);
```

**As you see the method has been formatted to be in 3 lines, how to stop this action**?

My code sample that do refactoring

```
            INodeFactory factory = ast.getASTNodeFactory();     
            IASTNode newNode = rewriter.createLiteralNode("( void )"+selectedNode.getRawSignature());
            rewriter.replace(selectedNode, newNode, null);
            Change change = rewriter.rewriteAST();
            change = change.perform(new NullProgressMonitor());
```

Comment: I believe this happened due to auto code formatting, how to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two options:

1. Configure CDT's built-in formatter to format the code the way you like it. In this case, based on the appearance of the "New code", it looks like Line `Wrapping -> Function calls -> Arguments -> Line wrapping policy` is set to one of the "Wrap all elements" options. You can change it to something you like better.
2. Implement the `org.eclipse.cdt.core.CodeFormatter` extension point to provide an alternative formatter that behaves differently from the default code formatter (for example, it could do nothing).

   **UPDATE**: I don't know where to find an example of this, but assuming you're familiar with implementing Eclipse extension points in general, [here is the reference](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_cdt_core_CodeFormatter.html) for this one. The steps would be:

   1. Write a class that extends `org.eclipse.cdt.core.formatter.CodeFormatter` and implements the `format()` method
   2. Ad an `<extension ...>` tag to your plugin's `plugin.xml` referencing your class

Comment: 1-I will go for the second option, could you give me a link to follow as I couldn't find any examples of this,
2-What if I need to add newline "\n" with rewriter#createLiteralNode method, how can this be achieved

Comment: Also I notice this line below also change the code formatting, is there any way to prevent this?

rewriter.replace(node, node.copy(), null);

Comment: @MostafaHassan: Please see my update about option #2.

Comment: Thanks very much @HighCommander4
I was able to keep the same fomat by doing this three steps
1-Configure CDT's Preferences-> code style -> fomratter ->Edit -> Line Wrapping tab -> Function calls -> Arguments -> Line wrapping policy
2-Line Wrapping tab-> Checkbox  "Never join already wrapped lines"
3-Configure CDT's Preferences-> Editor -> checkbox Ask for confirmation

I will also try the explained option you provided
Thanks alot